# Is there a way to fix javascript "touch" events firing twice on IOS devices? (Video example included)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ios, iphone

I'm working on a webpage that uses a carousel to show content on smaller screen sizes. I cooked up some javascript to create a "swipe" function on mobile devices and it works perfectly on android devices. However, on SOME iPhones (ones running the newer versions of IOS) the event seems to be triggered twice.

I've been researching this for various days, and although I've seen some similar scenarios, none are quite the same. Usually, the similar scenarios that I've found have two events being binded and thats what triggers the function twice. For example, $button.bind("touchstart click");

That, however, is *not* my problem.

*My* problem is that the $("#mobileCarousel").on("touchstart") seems to be firing twice on iPhones with the newer IOSs. I have no other events being binded, just the "touch"

Here is a video example of what is happening: https://youtu.be/8XGMKTpUUrI

I've included the js, css, and html.

I've been losing sleep over this, so any tips/solutions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated. :D

```js
$("#mobileCarousel").carousel({
  interval: 10000
})

$("#mobileCarousel").on("touchstart", function(event){
        var xClick = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
    $(this).one("touchmove", function(event){
        var xMove = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
        if( Math.floor(xClick - xMove) > 3 ){
            $(this).carousel('next');
            console.log("the touch event is firing twice.");
        }
        else if( Math.floor(xClick - xMove) < -3 ){
            $(this).carousel('prev');
            console.log("the touch event is firing twice.");
        }
    });
    $(".carousel").on("touchend", function(){
            $(this).off("touchmove");
    });
});

$(".carousel carousel-item").each(function(){
  var minPerSlide = 3;
  var nextElement = $(this).next();
  if(!nextElement.length){
    nextElement = $(this).siblings(":first");
  }
  nextElement.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  for (var i = 0; i < minPerSlide; i++) {
    nextElement = nextElement.next();
    if(!nextElement.length){
      nextElement = $(this).siblings(":first");

    }
    nextElement.children(":first-child").clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 993px) {
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item > div {
    display: none;
  }
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item > div:first-child {
    display: block;

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid carousel-container d-lg-none d-xl-none">
      <div id="mobileCarousel" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="carousel-item active">

              <div class="card index-card border-success">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <img src="code icon.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <p class="pTagsForCardTitles">&ltHTML&gt and CSS3</p>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <p class="pTagsForCards d-flex justify-content-center">We design and program your website from scratch and to
                    your liking. No restrictive templates! Have the website you have always dreamt of for your business.</p>
                </div>
              </div>

          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">

              <div class="card index-card border-success">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <img src="shield icon.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <p class="pTagsForCardTitles">Online Security</p>
                </div>
                <p class="pTagsForCards d-flex justify-content-center">Tropiweb supplies SSL security certificates to every
                page it produces. Keep your transactions and clients' sensitive informations out of the wrong hands.</p>
              </div>

          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">

              <div class="card index-card border-success">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <img src="search icon.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <p class="pTagsForCardTitles">Search Engine Optimization</p>
                </div>
                <p class="pTagsForCards d-flex justify-content-center">We optimize your web-page's &ltmeta&gt, &ltalt&gt, and
                  &lttitle&gt tags in order to maximize the probability of potential clients finding you through any search engine</p>
              </div>

          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">

              <div class="card index-card border-success">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <img src="responsive icon.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <p class="pTagsForCardTitles">Sleek and Responsive</p>
                </div>
                <p class="pTagsForCards d-flex justify-content-center">Your website is designed with cross-platform compatability as a priority.
                  No matter the web-browser or device (tablet, laptop, or phone) your page will always function properly.</p>
              </div>

          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">

              <div class="card index-card border-success">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <img src="money icon.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <p class="pTagsForCardTitles">E-Commerce Solutions</p>
                </div>
                <p class="pTagsForCards d-flex justify-content-center">Run your online shop right from your very own website. Validate transactions,
                  keep stock of your merchandise, charge applicable sales taxes, and ship your product with no hassle.</p>
              </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#mobileCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span>
              <img class="carousel-arrow-right" src="flecha-de.png" alt="">
            </span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#mobileCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span>
              <img class="carousel-arrow-left" src="flecha-iz.png" alt="">
            </span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I'm sure this isn't the problem, but one thing I noticed that I'm not sure was intentional or  not. When adding touchMove, you use `this` however to remove it, you remove it from ALL of the `.carousel`s. Shouldn't it be : `$(this).on("touchend", function(){`?

Comment: Hey, @imvain2. In case you were curious, the issue was caused by my usage of old versions of jQuery and Bootstrap. As soon as I incorporated the most recent versions of the library/framework, it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after many sleepless nights and debugging I fixed the issue. Apparently the issue was that I was using an old deprecated version of jQuery. Once I started using the latest version of jQuery, the issue went away.